# Automatic animation jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there any way to get an image to automatically animate using jquery?  I would like on specific element to animate after load up of the page.  So far all I can find is animation after a click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use animations anywhere. Just call the animation like you would inside of the `click`, but do it outside of a `click`, like in your `document.ready` for example.

```
$(function(){
    $("element").animate({..animation stuffs..});
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j9kWz/)**

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Look at the ready event, likely what you need.  You can have multiple functions passed to ready().